# Computing SUM within FOREACH

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Let's say I have the following

```
DATA = foreach INPUT {
   //..
   generate group, count(name) as total;
}
```

I'll end up with a relation where the key is grouped by name

```
('mike', 'someprop', 10)
('mike', 'otherprop', 3)
('doug', 'xprop', 5)
...
```

And I want to get the **sum of the top 10 for each name**:

```
ALIAS = group DATA by name;
RESULT = foreach ALIAS {
   SORTED = ORDER DATA by total desc;
   TOP10 = LIMIT SORTED 10;

   //doesn't work! can't have GROUP inside FOREACH
   AGG = group TOP10 ALL;
   TOPTOTAL = foreach AGG generate SUM(AGG.total);

   generate group, TOPTOTAL;
}
```

How can I compute a value (SUM,COUNT,ETC) for a **relation** inside a `foreach`? Currently there's no way to apply a `GROUP ALL` inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is just a function that takes a bag as its argument, and you can create this bag by projecting from `TOP10`:

```
ALIAS = group DATA by name;
RESULT = foreach ALIAS {
   SORTED = ORDER DATA by total desc;
   TOP10 = LIMIT SORTED 10;
   generate group, SUM(TOP10.total);
}
```